# exception handling with try/except in python 2.7

Tags: types, input, error-handling, python-2.7, try-except

I'm experimenting with exception handling / error trapping and was wondering why the below code doesn't work. I'm using python 2.7. I understand the difference between `input()` and `raw_input()` and understand that `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()` in Python 3.0. If I enter an integer then the code keeps looping until I enter a string. I get the below error message when entering a string. Is there a way around this or is this just one of those python quirks?

```py
  File "<some_directory_path_goes_here>", line 30, in <module>
    enterAge = input('Enter your age as an integer: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '<user_entered_string_goes_here>' is not defined
```

In python 2.7 it would seem to me that the code should still work.

```py
from types import IntType
age = 0
while True:
    enterAge = input('Enter your age as an integer: ')
    try:
        if type(enterAge) is IntType:
            num = enterAge
            age = age + num
            print str(age) + ' is old!'

    except TypeError:
        print 'You did\'t enter an integer'
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `try`-`except` is that you don't check all the necessary conditions beforehand. In your case you don't need to check for types inside `try`. Because of the `if` statement the exception will not be raised when it should.

Also, you should definitely use `raw_input()` on Python 2 and keep in mind that it *always* returns a `str`. What can differ is the result of `int(enterAge)`:

```py
In [1]: int('4')
Out[1]: 4

In [2]: int('4f')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/lev/<ipython-input-2-523c771e7a8e> in <module>()
----> 1 int('4f')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4f'
```

This is what you need to try in the `try` block and catch the `ValueError`.

Edit: Apparently I need to clarify the answer a little, so I'll show how in my opinion the code should look:

```py
age = 0
while True:
    enterAge = raw_input('Enter your age as an integer: ')
    try:
        age += int(enterAge)
        print age, 'is old!'

    except ValueError:
        print "You didn't enter an integer"
        break
```

Comment: "Because of the if statement the exception will not be raised when it should."  

I disagree based on the below code, on orange juice the exception is raised  

`fridge = {'eggs': 8, 'cheese': 12, 'butter': 4, 'milk': 17}`  
`try:`  
    `if fridge['milk'] > 0:`  
        `print 'Drink some milk'`  

`except KeyError as error:`  
    `print 'There is no %s' % error`  

`try:`  
    `if fridge['orange juice'] > 0:`  
        `print 'Drink some orange juice'`  

`except KeyError as error:`  
    `print 'There is no %s' % error`  

Why can't I get the linebreaks to work?

Comment: @MichaelSwartz In this case the exception is caused when the condition is evaluated inside `if`: `fridge['orange juice'] > 0` itself causes the exception, so this is the correct use of `try`. But in the question the possible problem is the wrong type, so the `try` is there to account for it, but `if` checks the same thing. `type(enterAge) is IntType` can't produce an exception, that's the difference. And yeah, you can't have linebreaks in comments. Sometimes it's frustrating. You can edit your question in response to answers and comments, though.

Comment: So my code is wrong because something like `("x" * 100) is ("x" * 100)` is `False` but `("x" * 100) == ("x" * 100)` is `True` because `is` tests for identity and not equality?

Comment: Not sure about the use of `is` in the context (it may work, as a simple test shows), but my point is that your code is wrong that you put an **exception-safe** piece of code in a `try` block. You made it safe by using `if`. You should either use `if` or `try` in the code shown in your question. Another mistake you made, as I mentioned before, is that the user input returned by `raw_input` will always be `str` unless you explicitly convert it, so you need to account for that.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz I edited the answer, hope it helps. Feel free to ask.